# Equation of egg-shaped curve

Tags: geometry, functions, trigonometry

I'm a high school student doing a modelling project. On this page here (https://nyjp07.com/index_egg_E.html) I've found a suitable equation, which is equation 9 in section 1 of the page, and wanted to understand where it came from. However, I'm already stuck on the first step. Quoting the explanation: "The point $Q$ is supposed to move on the x-axis co-sinusoidally according to the angle theta of the segment $PQ$ as the following", what does it mean for a point to move on the axis co-sinusoidally? Then they pulled out the equation
$$ F_x=l \cos \theta$$
What is the $l$ here, and what does that equation mean?

I'm just completely lost, can someone help?

Comment: The equation $F_x=l \cos\theta$ is equivalent to "a point moves on the axis co-sinusoidally": one is stated in algebra, the other in words. As an example of how this could arise, consider the hand of a clock: its vertical position relative to the center of the clock is $l\cos\theta$ where $l$ is the length of the hand and $\theta$ is the angle made with the vertical.

Comment: Have you seen this [article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00004-014-0189-5#:~:text=an%20egg%2Dshape%20(or%206,sharing%20a%20common%20tangent%20(Fig.) about egg shapes constructed with circular arcs ?

Comment: @Semiclassical Thank you, it makes much more sense now

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for the article